# In SalesTable form, how to protect salesLine dimensions when items are already picked up?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

In our Dynamics Ax 2009 configuration, we would like to avoid stock dimensions to be changed once the items are picked up or delivered. 
Sometimes users change the facial stock dimensions (warehouse, location) on the sales lines while transactions have already been registered.

I'm not aware of a way to protect this by a change in Stock or Sales parameters.

I try to solve this, with a change in `active()` method in the `Salesline` datasource of the `SalesTable` form, which calls a specific method :

```
if (InventDim_Ds.allowEdit())
{
    if (SalesLine.pickedInTotalSalesUnit() != 0 || SalesLine.DeliveredInTotal() != 0)
    {
        InventDim_Ds.allowEdit(false);
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work, or works too well : now it is impossible to change the stock dimensions, even if nothing has been picked or delivered.

I assume this has to do with the link between sales lines and dimensions, but I don't know how to fix my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On first glance, it looks like your issue is with:

> `if (InventDim_Ds.allowEdit())`

As it doesn't allow changes between lines.  If one line is picked, it will disable the `InventDim_Ds`, then when you move to the next `SalesLine` triggering the `active()` method, it will see that it's disabled and not enter the `if` statement.

Try this:

```
InventDim_ds.allowEdit(!salesLine.pickedInTotalSalesUnit() && !salesLine.deliveredInTotal());
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I wrote my code this way because I didn't know about other reasons that may allow edit on InventDim and supposed this datasource was actived at the same time as SalesLine. This way it is ok ;   I must assume to take control on Inventdim being editable or not.